# OutOfMemoryError android

Tags: android

В Маркете смотрю ошибки и обнаружил что стала появляться у некоторых пользователей эта ошибка. Картинки, которые загружаются в CircleImageView небольшие -- 120х120 пикселей. Почему такая ошибка может возникнуть?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream (BitmapFactory.java:856)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream (BitmapFactory.java:675)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream (Drawable.java:2228)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:4211)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:4085)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:2005)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1987)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable (Context.java:464)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri (ImageView.java:827)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource (ImageView.java:434)
at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setImageResource (CircleImageView.java:290)
at myfirstapp.RadioAdapter.getView (RadioAdapter.java:51)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView (AbsListView.java:2929)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView (ListView.java:1945)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown (ListView.java:719)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap (ListView.java:683)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll (AbsListView.java:7293)
at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run (AbsListView.java:6734)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:920)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:695)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:628)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:906)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Вот код адпатера

```
public class RadioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Radio> radios;

    RadioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Radio> radios) {
        this.context = context;
        this.radios = radios;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return radios.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return radios.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        }

        Radio radio = getRadio(i);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRadio)).setText(radio.title);
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRadio)).setImageResource(radio.image);

        return view;
    }

    Radio getRadio(int position) {
        return (Radio) getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Видимо где то остаются висеть ссылки на картинки и GC их не подчищает. В языках без GC это называется утечка.

Comment: Понятно.. Тут наверное программист программно как-то не может повлиять на это? Вручную подчищать или что-то такое

Comment: не просто может, а должен. Я бы начал с https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html и искал, кто кушает память. И начала бы смотреть на все статические поля внутри view/fragment. Очень часто оказывается, что делают адаптер для списка и он статическое поле.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос код адаптера

Comment: когда список прокручиваю на мониторе видно что памяти тратится немного больше, но это наверное логично. Во время прокрутки нет такого чтобы память прям в разы больше забивалась.

Comment: а я бы при этом ещё бы и переворачивал телефон с портретного в ландшафтний и обратно много много раз.

Comment: @Кокосовый почитайте здесь https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html, попробуйте реализовать decodeSampledBitmapFromResource